# De Rham cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have some question on De Rham cohomology: the first one is general. If we calculate De Rham cohomology of a manifold with Mayer-Vietoris sequences we discover that the cohomology is the difect of exactness of the sequence. So can I look at De Rham cohomology as the difficult to extend a local exact form defined on a open set to all manifold?

Comment: Absolutely you can!

Comment: Do you have a method to calaculate the De Rham cohomology of finite Grassmannians using spectral sequences?